# Set georeferenced extents of VRT file when calling GDALBuildVRT

Tags: python, vrt, gdalbuildvrt, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and gdalbuildvrt to write a program that loads hundreds of rasters. I want to set an area of interest, and only keep rasters (or portions of rasters) that fall in this area.

Here's an example pulled from the internet, using the 'te' flag from the command line to set a bounding box:

```
gdalbuildvrt -te 5.8887,50.3332,9.4702,52.5212 output.vrt -input_file_list
```

However, in the Python/Jupyter API, using BuildVRT, it isn't clear how to set the georeferenced extents:

```
outds = gd.BuildVRT(output.vrt, filelist, separate=True)
```

Simply adding 'te' causes a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some digging, the answer is within the documentation, but not on the main BuildVRT page:

http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#BuildVRTOptions

The answer to my above question is therefore to use the **outputBounds** argument, like so:

```
options = gd.BuildVRTOptions(outputBounds=(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), separate=True)

outds = gd.BuildVRT(outvrt, getfiles, options=options)
```